# 'Promise' is undefined error in ASP.NET Core SPA Template for Aurelia

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, single-page-application, aurelia

I have installed the ASP.NET Core SPA Templates:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

But when I try to open the site in I.E 11 I get error "'Promise' is undefined". What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: You need a Promise polyfill for IE11. Aurelia starter packs include **bluebird** [Bluebirdjs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: @Benny, you should post your comment as an answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: Thanks @AshleyGrant. Done

Answer (score 2):

You need a Promise polyfill for IE11. Aurelia starter packs include bluebird [Bluebirdjs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)